# Running VBA on Access via batch file (or similar file)

Tags: ms-access

I have a database provided to me externally. Unfortunately they've mistakely made a bunch of fields memo text rather than short text (fields I need to do JOINs on) and seem to have no intention of correcting their mistake (this is a UK government database after all).

I've written some VBA to convert the many memo fields to short text.

I will be getting new versions of this database all the time, so I can't store the conversion script in the database.

To save a bit of time is there a way of running this vba script on the database using something like a .bat file?

I know, for instance, that I can open Access 2013 via .bat using:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\myfilepath\myfile.mdb"
```

But I can't find much info on whether scripts written in VBA can subsequently be run via .bat on the opened database (particularly if the script is not already written in to the database).

Comment: You might consider to write an external VB.NET application that uses Access as an ODBC data source and makes necessary changes. That involves running an executable right after receiving new version of the database.

Comment: We don't have visual studio here, unfortunately.

Comment: @MattHall The solution proposed by @utkuerd is the best approach (I think)... as for getting Visual Studio, there's a free version available. Another option (although I've not tried it) is to use Python (freely available), and using the [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/); I found an example [here](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/226/2/) about how to use DAO in a Python Script (I assume you can do much more than a simple `select`)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will look in to those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have all your custom scripts live in another Access file of your creation. Every time you get a new database from wherever you can link those tables to your 'scripts database' and run your code there. You might not even need to link. You will probably just need the file path to your new database.

Yes, VB.NET is a good solution but you already wrote the code in VBA you might as well keep it in VBA. Access usually doesn't care if it is acting on tables/data in it's own file or another file.

You can get a handle on another Access file like this

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim wksp As DAO.Workspace
Set wksp = CreateWorkspace("AccessWorkspace", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set db = wksp.OpenDatabase("your file path")
```

Now you can use that `db` variable as though you had dome something like `Set db = CurrentDb`. Change table defs, execute queries, etc...

All you need to do is make a dashboard form on your 'scripts database' with a textbox and a file picker functionality. then on a button click use the file path in your textbox to get a handle on your other DB. Execute the code you wrote already normally.